# Прошу помочь разобраться с селекторами в Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Добрый вечер, помогите пожалуйста разобраться с логикой данного кода.

Есть 9 блоков, при наведении на один блок нужно чтобы картинка менялась, на ту что скрыта. 
Как правильно минимизировать код, чтобы каждый раз не прописывать для каждого селектора? Пробовал циклы и прочую лабудень, и уже окончательно запутался.
помогите пожалуйста.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
       $('.tov-item-img').eq('0').mouseover(function() {
        $('.tov-img-hidden').eq('0').css("top","0px");
        $('.tov-img-main').eq('0').css("top","0px");
    });
        $('.tov-item-img').eq('0').mouseout(function() {
        $('.tov-img-hidden').eq('0').css("top","-240px");
        $('.tov-img-main').eq('0').css("top","-240px");
    });
        $('.tov-item-img').eq('1').mouseover(function() {
        $('.tov-img-hidden').eq('1').css("top","0px");
        $('.tov-img-main').eq('1').css("top","0px");
    });
        $('.tov-item-img').eq('1').mouseout(function() {
        $('.tov-img-hidden').eq('1').css("top","-240px");
        $('.tov-img-main').eq('1').css("top","-240px");
    });
});
```

```css
.tov-item-img{
    width: 200px;
    height: 240px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.tov-img-main{
    background: blue;
    width: 200px;
    height: 240px;
    position: relative;
    top:-240px;
    transition: 1s;
}

.tov-img-hidden{
    background: green;
    width: 200px;
    height: 240px;
    position: relative;
    top:-240px;
    transition: 1s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tov-item-body">
 <div class="tov-item-img">
  <div class="tov-img-hidden"></div> 
  <div class="tov-img-main"></div>
 </div>
 <p>Описание товара 1</p>
</div>
<div class="tov-item-body">
 <div class="tov-item-img">
  <div class="tov-img-hidden"></div> 
  <div class="tov-img-main"></div>
 </div>
 <p>Описание товара 2</p>
</div>

<!-- и ещё таких 7 штук -->
```

Answer (score 1):

Используйте  `$(this).find(selector)` чтобы найти элемент внутри активного элемента:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.tov-item-img').mouseover(function() {
    $(this).find('.tov-img-hidden').css("top", "0px");
    $(this).find('.tov-img-main').css("top", "0px");
  });
  $('.tov-item-img').mouseout(function() {
    $(this).find('.tov-img-hidden').css("top", "-240px");
    $(this).find('.tov-img-main').css("top", "-240px");
  });

});
```

```css
.tov-item-img {
  width: 200px;
  height: 240px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.tov-img-main {
  background: blue;
  width: 200px;
  height: 240px;
  position: relative;
  top: -240px;
  transition: 1s;
}
.tov-img-hidden {
  background: green;
  width: 200px;
  height: 240px;
  position: relative;
  top: -240px;
  transition: 1s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tov-item-body">
  <div class="tov-item-img">
    <div class="tov-img-hidden"></div>
    <div class="tov-img-main"></div>
  </div>
  <p>Описание товара 1</p>
</div>
<div class="tov-item-body">
  <div class="tov-item-img">
    <div class="tov-img-hidden"></div>
    <div class="tov-img-main"></div>
  </div>
  <p>Описание товара 2</p>
</div>

<!-- и ещё таких 7 штук -->
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, знал что надо this, но не знал как применить.
Там ещё eq(0) Вы забыли убрать. Но логика понятна. Ещё раз спасибо

Comment: @SergeyNovikov Я убрал, но вы успели посмотреть.

Comment: @Crantisz на самом деле до сих пор осталось.

Comment: Точно. Но в этом месте она ничего не портит

Answer (score 0):

Использовал `on` чтоб дойти до каждого элемента, нет надобности писать код под каждый элемент.
и через `children()` ставлю в `css` все параметры

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('.tov-item-img').on('mouseover',function(){
           $(this).children().css("top","0px");

})
$('.tov-item-img').on('mouseout',function(){
           $(this).children().css("top","-240px");
})
    
});
```

```css
.tov-item-img{
    width: 200px;
    height: 240px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.tov-img-main{
    background: blue;
    width: 200px;
    height: 240px;
    position: relative;
    top:-240px;
    transition: 1s;
}

.tov-img-hidden{
    background: green;
    width: 200px;
    height: 240px;
    position: relative;
    top:-240px;
    transition: 1s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tov-item-body">
 <div class="tov-item-img">
  <div class="tov-img-hidden"></div> 
  <div class="tov-img-main"></div>
 </div>
 <p>Описание товара 1</p>
</div>
<div class="tov-item-body">
 <div class="tov-item-img">
  <div class="tov-img-hidden"></div> 
  <div class="tov-img-main"></div>
 </div>
 <p>Описание товара 2</p>
</div>

<!-- и ещё таких 7 штук -->
```

Comment: проверьте мой код

Answer (score 0):

Есть более красивое решение, чем показано выше, без еще большей избыточности. Убирает лишний div, лишнее правило css к нему и еще больше минимизирует js.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.tov-item-img').hover(
    function() {
      $(this).children('.tov-img-hidden').css("top", "0px");
    },
    function() {
      $(this).children('.tov-img-hidden').css("top", "-240px");
    });
});
```

```css
.tov-item-img {
  width: 200px;
  height: 240px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: blue;
}
.tov-img-hidden {
  background: green;
  width: 200px;
  height: 240px;
  position: relative;
  top: -240px;
  transition: 1s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tov-item-body">
  <div class="tov-item-img">
    <div class="tov-img-hidden"></div>
  </div>
  <p>Описание товара 1</p>
</div>
<div class="tov-item-body">
  <div class="tov-item-img">
    <div class="tov-img-hidden"></div>
  </div>
  <p>Описание товара 2</p>
</div>
```

Comment: в чилдрен, не обязательно прописывать класс

Comment: конкретно в моем варианте да, но лучше оставить - так будет и читабельнее, и надежнее в случае изменения кода в будущем.